# Como obter o stack trace mesmo que uma exceção não seja lançada?

Tags: c#, .net, stack-trace

Sabemos que podemos [pegar o *stack trace* quando uma exceção é lançada](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.exception.stacktrace?view=net-8.0&WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397). Mas e se eu quiser saber como está a pilha sem ter que dar um *throw*, é possível? Teria que criar uma exceção sem lançá-la?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

É possível usar a classe [`StackTrace`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.stacktrace?view=net-8.0&WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397) que fica no [`System.Diagnostics`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics?view=net-8.0&WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397). Não precisa criar a exceção, muito menos lança-la. No momento que criar um objeto desta classe o .NET montará o estado que a pilha está e poderá acessar essa informação, como texto via [`ToString()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.stacktrace.tostring?view=net-8.0&WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397) ou pegar os frames com [`GetFrames()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.stacktrace.getframe?view=net-8.0&WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397).